# How can I call Meteor method once for two clients?

Tags: node.js, meteor

Im trying to build simple game on meteor. When two players are registered in the game, they are redirected to the page of the game, and the server method is called. The method simply updates mongo collection with new game information and starts the interval, which will check for game end time:

```js
//on client
Template.Game.onCreated(function() {
  Meteor.call('game', gameId, function(error) {
    if (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  });
});

//on server
Meteor.methods({
  'game': function(gameId) {
    var game = Games.findOne({
      _id: gameId
    });

    if (game) {
      //here update collection...

      var interval = Meteor.setInterval(function() {
        var now = Date.now();
        if (now >= game.endTime) {
          Meteor.clearInterval(interval);
        }
      }, 1000);
    }
  }
});
```

But the problem is that the method is running twice and creating two intervals. I know that Meteor creates a new fiber for each request made from the client. And so turns out that methods are called at the same time, and running independently from each other. I don't know maybe there is a way to run two requests in one fiber) maybe this will help, or somehow else solve this, i am new at this. Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: A better approach would be to create the interval (why not a timeout?) when the game is actually started, by the code that registers the second user. If time sync is your problem, you can use a package such as [timesync](https://github.com/mizzao/meteor-timesync).

Comment: @MaterAm Thanks for answer. It could solve the problem, but sorry i dont mentioned that the game consists of five rounds, and then the round time ends, client should call this method again, update game info and create new interval which  will check for round end.

Comment: **//here update collection...** What collection is updated? Is it related to the new group of two gamers?

Comment: @Kishor Yes it is. Actually it is simple quiz game. Then method is called, this current game is updated with new question and new round is started.

Comment: Then you can also have another boolean field in the collection like countDownStarted. When updating collection, if countDownStarted is false, you can set this flag to true and call setInterval. For the second call since the countDownStarted is true, you don't call the setInterval. But this may not work because of asynchronous reads.

Comment: Another approach might be to add one userId to game record when creating the game and check if `this.userId === game.userId` to set interval. This way only one user's call will set interval.

Comment: @Kishor Thanks for answers. I think the first approach won't work, but the second is nice, will try it. Thanks. But it still not so good, if this users connection is lost, so the game couldnt continue, right?

Comment: Yes, you are right. What is the `setInterval` doing actually. Since in the sample code, it just checks the `now >= game.endTime` and clears interval but doesn't execute another other code when `now < game.endTime`. If we know the actual output, then may be we can think of other better ways to achieve the desired result. :)

Comment: @Kishor When now >= game.endTime It updates current game document, sets roundEndTime flag to true and when this flag is true, the client side timer is stopped and this method is called again to start new round. I don't know is this the best way to do this)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Note: I didn't try this but I am answering so that you can make suitable adjustments to get it working.**

Based on your question and comments, it might be better to use `observeChanges`. In the `games.js` collection file or the file where you declared `Games` collection,

```
var handle = Games.find({}).observeChanges({
     added: function (id, game) {
         //if first round is started immediately then create a setInterval here.
     },
     changed: function (id, fields) {
         //whenever round information is updated, you can set interval for the next round (if next round is available) here.
        // you can use "fields" parameter passed to this function
     }
});
```

The `added` callback will run whenever a new record is inserted in to `Games` collection. `id` is the newly inserted game's id, `game` is the newly inserted game document.
The `updated` callback will run whenever an existing record is updated in `Games` collection. `id` is the updated game's id, `fields` are **only** newly updated fields in game document.

See meteor document for further understanding: http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/observe_changes

Hope it helps.

Comment: It worked with some adjustments. you gave me a hint in the right direction. Thank you. I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score -1):

I think instead of call method on template created.
Perform the action after login.
On client side user will login.
On server side user authenticate and find the other user, which is free. So after finding the user you can create the game and pass the game to your game data to template.